# "git status" is showing files it shouldn't

Tags: git, msysgit

I've had the same problem happen twice in the last couple of weeks where git just seems to wig out for some reason and list files in `git status` that it shouldn't be listing as changed/new/ect...

version: `git version 1.8.1.msysgit.1`

Screenshot:
[image]

Here is my contents of my `.gitignore` file:

```
#ignore thumbnails created by windows
Thumbs.db
#Ignore files build by Visual Studio
*.obj
*.exe
*.pdb
*.user
*.aps
*.pch
*.vspscc
*_i.c
*_p.c
*.ncb
*.suo
*.tlb
*.tlh
*.bak
*.cache
*.ilk
*.log
[Bb]in
[Dd]ebug*/
*.lib
*.sbr
obj/
[Rr]elease*/
_ReSharper*/
[Tt]est[Rr]esult*
*.sln
.gitignore
.orig
*.psess
#word temp files
~*.docx
*.tmp
```

Everything in green in the screenshot is incorrect. First, all of the .resx files are not new and they were there before i started my changes. Second, the last green file (.cache) is not only specifically in my `.gitignore` file so is the directory (obj/).

The branch i'm on was just created yesterday and here is one of the files its showing in green:
[image]

As you can see its dated 2/19/13 and i just made my changes to this project today.

Everything in red are actually what i changed. I only changed one file (the bottom file in red) in the project that all the "incorrect" new files are coming from and then built.

Anyone know whats going on?

Update: Executing `git reset` Fixed the problem. Here is the output:

```
Unstaged changes after reset:
D       Correspondence/STAR/Participants/Claim - Framework/Word/C_PAR_ClmFrmWrk_SuppRptFrmEC1.docx
D       Correspondence/STAR/Participants/Claim - Framework/Word/C_PAR_ClmFrmWrk_SuppRptFrmEC1_DT.docx
D       Correspondence/STAR/Participants/Claim - Framework/Word/C_PAR_ClmFrmWrk_SuppRptFrmEC2.docx
D       Correspondence/STAR/Participants/Claim - Framework/Word/C_PAR_ClmFrmWrk_SuppRptFrmEC2_DT.docx
D       Correspondence/STAR/Participants/Claim - Framework/Word/C_PAR_ClmFrmWrk_SuppRptFrmEP1.docx
D       Correspondence/STAR/Participants/Claim - Framework/Word/C_PAR_ClmFrmWrk_SuppRptFrmEP1_DT.docx
D       Correspondence/STAR/Participants/Claim - Framework/Word/C_PAR_ClmFrmWrk_SuppRptFrmEP2.docx
D       Correspondence/STAR/Participants/Claim - Framework/Word/C_PAR_ClmFrmWrk_SuppRptFrmEP2_DT.docx
D       SQL/STAR/Stored Procedures/s_ClmTrackingRecordSEL_ResendSuppByTrackingRecordID.sql
M       Shared Objects/Components/TRSEnums/TRSEnums.vb
M       Shared Objects/Components/TrsPartFilterScreens/VB Code/ReportRequest.Partial7.Miscellaneous.vb
```

Comment: it lists some document files as deleted. do those  still exist? if not, you should find out what (in your build process or otherwise) deleted those

Comment: @NevikRehnel Yes those deletes are correct and purposeful. There isn't really a build process but just a generic "build project" right in visual studio. Everything in red is correct.

Comment: Files won't usually show up under "Changes to be committed" unless someone has run `git add` on either the files or the directory the files are in (i.e. things like `git add -A`, `git add -u` [if the files are already tracked and have been modified], `git add <dirname>`, etc.). It does not appear that `*.resx` is in your ignore list. Also, the fact that `*.cache` is in your `.gitignore` doesn't automatically untrack files, so if that one was added before the pattern in `.gitignore`, it will continue to be tracked.

Comment: @twalberg Thanks for the reply. Yes the *.resx files should not be in the ignore file but only added when they changed or are actually added. My .gitignore file hasn't changed for at least a month. After thinking what has changed in my setup lately i remember i just installed the "Git Source Control Provider" extension for visual studio 2012 after i applied update 2. I think both of these problems happened after i installed it. I tried it anyways and prefer the command line (way more power). Investingating further.....

Comment: Are your files on disk named `.resx` or `.resX`? Git is case-sensitive, even if Windows is not. If the files on disk do not have the same casing as the files in source control, then depending on the internal methods used to check for changes you could see inconsistencies.

Answer (score 0):

After much testing, i have figured out what the problem is: `Git Source Control Provider`. If i build any of our projects that haven't previously been built in my branch the problem happens again. For example i built our email object:
[image]

So how do you fix it? Remove the `"Git Source Control Provider"` and the problem is corrected. Unfortunately every time i open a project now i get the "The source control provider associated with this solution could not be found" which i did not get pre `update 2`. Unfortunately i don't think there is anyway to uninstall `update 2`.

If you run into the same problem just do a `git reset` to fix things but you will have to remove the `"Git Source Control Provider"` if you don't want it to happen again.

Comment: Sensibly, the git source control provider adds new files to your repository if they aren't in a `.gitignore`.  In any case, if you don't want that message, you should unbind it as the source control provider: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181375(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: @EdwardThomson but thats the whole issue if you look at everything above the files are in the .gitignore. Please read above.

Comment: I've read your `.gitignore` several times now; which line do you think those changes should match?

Comment: Git Source Control Provider shouldn't be changing anything in your repository unless you specifically request it (e.g. using it to stage files or make a commit). Is your repository publicly accessible by any chance?